# Integrating JSF PrimeFaces and Spring annotation

Tags: spring, jsf

We have a application which is using jsf2.0 (primefaces) and Spring annotations

We have tabs and lot of components and buttons...and  we need to persist data between tabs...and on diff  button clicks.

I am using @ViewScoped for the variables to keep the scope to Page only. 
For a business logic we are using Spring and hence @Component instead of @managedBean

But after a research I found that I cannot use @viewScope with the @Component. 
(And I cannot use @requestScope in my code .... )

Is there any alternative of ViewScope that I can use or any other alternative to keep scope my variable as Page?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can. But you need to register the managed bean to Spring IoC Context instead of to Faces context.

The most important thing is adding spring bean resolver to faces-config.xml.

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
       org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
```

See in detail here: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/

Comment: But as I said we are using spring annotations for the business logic and using @Component to identify the bean automatically...
So still I will have to register my bean class ?
Also as per the document in the link , the scope is kept as 'session' .... 
If I apply this given concept  can I change scope to page ??? Will this work ??? ( Sorry asking these questions without  doing, but I'll try that if nothing works ) ....

Comment: Yes, you still can use either Component, ManagedBean, or SessionScoped annotation. Have you seen the reference? There is clearer and more complete explanation there.